# i don't know how to map this complex number given these conditions

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Here are the conditions:

[image]

$w=$

[image: w=]

After separating the real and imaginary parts of w. I don't know how to transform from the z plane to the w.
[image]

The area between the lines are all the posible values of z.

What should i do next to obtain the grafic in the w plain?

Comment: Have you tried plugging in just the boundaries of $z$ -- eg $x=0$, $y=0$, and $y=x$? Note that for an arbitrary 2D transform, the boundaries of the input aren't necessarily the boundaries of the output. But, for most invertible ones, they should be.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: the idea of choosing $y=kx$,where $k\ge1$, arises from the process of run over the region $D$ radial-like and the selection $y=x$ with $x>0$ correspond to the orange border, which inserted on $\frac{z-i}{z+I}$ gives you a parametric form of a circle .

Answer (score 0):

Super-Hint:

Simplifying the choice $y=x$ the image is
$${\dfrac{2x^2-1}{(x+1)^2+x^2}+i \dfrac{-2x}{(x+1)^2+x^2}}.$$

But for another choice, say  $y=3x$ the image is
$${\dfrac{10x^2-1}{(3x+1)^2+x^2}+i \dfrac{-6x}{(3x+1)^2+x^2}}.$$

Comment: then with a robot https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=parametric+plot+%7B%282x%5E2-1%29%2F%28%28x%2B1%29%5E2%2Bx%5E2%29+%7D+%2C%28-2x+%29%2F%28%28x%2B1%29%5E2%2Bx%5E2%29+ .

Answer (score 0):

HINT….Start by inverting the relationship between $z$ and $w$ to get $$z=\frac{i(w+1)}{1-w}$$
Now write $$w=u+iv$$ and do some algebra to get expressions for the real and imaginary parts of $z$ in terms of $u$ and $v$
You get $$z=\frac{-2v+i(1-u^2-v^2)}{(1-u)^2+v^2}$$

The conditions on $z$, i.e. $$\frac{\pi}{4}<\arg z<\frac{\pi}{2}$$ can be summarized as: $$Re(z)>0$$
$$Im(z)>0$$
$$Im(z)>Re(z)$$

This will enable you to set up some inequalities for $u$ and $v$ and sketch the required region in the $w$ plane